# Unable to connect Ethereum Parity node. RPC port: 8545 is open

Tags: json-rpc

I run local Parity node on my Win 8.1 computer and was trying to check how RPC is Working
But it is not working

I tried PostMan:

http://127.0.0.1:8445

```
Content-Type application/json
Body {"method":"parity_accountsInfo","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

Get answer: Could not get any response

I tried CURL( like Parity documentation said ):

```
curl --data '{"method":"eth_accounts","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
```

get answer error

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0":{"code": - 32700, message:"Parse error", "data":null}, "id": null}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Hi there. What options did you start Parity with? (Also, in your PostMan example, you've used `8445`, not `8545`. I think that's probably a typo in your question, rather than a typo in PostMan, as your CURL example uses the correct port and still fails. Thought I'd mention it anyway.)